# ProcessMessagesAsync method not firing in Azure service bus subscription

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

I am using Azure service bus for messaging between my two .Net core Web API Applications.
By using topicClient I am able to send the message to ABS.
But however while using the subscription client to receive the message, I am facing this issue.

**ProcessMessagesAsync - method is not firing until I give "Console.Read();"**. I cannot give this because I am using Web API.

**How else, can I fire this ProcessMessagesAsync method** - which read my message perfectly.

Thanks in advance.

```
    public async Task GetMessageFromSubscription()
        {

        subscriptionClient = new SubscriptionClient(ServiceBusConnectionString, TopicName, SubscriptionName);

                RegisterOnMessageHandlerAndReceiveMessages();
                //  Console.Read();  ------- Without this line 

                await subscriptionClient.CloseAsync();
           }

 public void RegisterOnMessageHandlerAndReceiveMessages()
        {
            var messageHandlerOptions = new MessageHandlerOptions(ExceptionReceivedHandler);
            subscriptionClient.RegisterMessageHandler(ProcessMessagesAsync, messageHandlerOptions);
         }


        private async Task ProcessMessagesAsync(Message message, CancellationToken token)
        {
               var messageBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body);
                var serviceBusMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WorkIntakeItem>(messageBody);
                await subscriptionClient.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);

         }
```

Answer (score 1):

**It's a loop that is running as along as the process is running. When process ends, the handler will be terminated.**

If you have a continues stream of messages, handler (aka message pump) is a suitable option. If you just need to receive one message and exit, then there's an blocking option of Message [`MessageReceiver.ReceiveAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.core.messagereceiver.receiveasync?view=azure-dotnet). You control the app to you when to close it.

```
static IMessageReceiver messageReceiver;
RegisterOnMessageHandlerAndReceiveMessages();
Message message = await messageReceiver.ReceiveAsync();
await messageReceiver.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);
await messageReceiver.CloseAsync();
await subscriptionClient.CloseAsync();
```

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/tree/master/samples/DotNet/GettingStarted/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/SendReceiveUsingMessageSenderReceiver).